# Why isn't the boolean variable being detected?

Tags: jquery

the console is not detecting `overExpand` as true at the end. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var transLayer = $('.transparentBg');
var overExpand = false;
var overUl = false;


$(transLayer).hide();
console.log('transLayer hide'); // this is being logged

$('#header .nav .wrapper > ul > li.expand').hover(function(){ 
    overExpand = true;  
    console.log(overExpand);// this works = true    
}, function(){ 
    overUl = true;
});

console.log(overExpand); // this shows false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is false because the code that sets the value to `true` is never run.

You have `overExpand = true` inside of a hover event handler. That code won't be run until the event is fired. The `console.log(overExpand)` will surely execute before the event is fired therefore overExpand will still be false.

If you want to see the value after it is set to `true`, you should log from inside the handler:

```
$('header .nav .wrapper > ul > li.expand').hover(function(){
    overExpand = true;
    console.log(overExpand);
}, function(){
    overUl = true;
});
```

If you're really expecting it to be true the way it is currently written, you'll have to restructure the code a good deal.

Comment: I updated the code in my question a little. Yes you're right, adding `console.log` does work in the hover event. But is there a way to have that boolean change detected from outside of the event?

Comment: @muudless - My original answer still applies. Since the value doesn't get set until the event is fired, code that executes after adding the handler but before the handler fires will still see the original value.

Comment: thanks, i understand now. i think i just need to fire another function when the hover event is being called or something.

Answer (score 1):

Add your `console.log()` inside the hover function.

```
$('#header .nav .wrapper > ul > li.expand').hover(function(){ 
    overExpand = true;    
    console.log(overExpand);   
}, function(){ 
    overUl = true;
});
```

This will create a new log in your console each time you hover over the element, as this is when the function is executed. In your previous code, the call to `console.log()` happens before the hover function is triggered.